# Best practice for insert data into relation table with many columns (no ORM)

Tags: java, spring, database, jdbc, insert

I have table REPORT. This table have relation with (for example) table CLIENT and table TAG.

In the request I get one REPORT with 1-20 CLIENT and 1-20 TAG. I need insert it in DB (postgre).

How I can do it if I can use only JdbcTemplate? (All ORM forbidden). Of course with transactional and rollback? I need only some idea.

Comment: You have a table REPORT for reports, TAG for tags and CLIENT for clients. Do you also have relation tables like REPORT_TAG and REPORT_CLIENT?

Comment: @morsor no, only this 3 table. Table have foreign key for relation. In REPORT no info about client and tag, but in tag and client table exists column reportId

Comment: So a TAG or CLIENT may only be related to one REPORT?

Comment: @morsor yes, you are right

Comment: Do you have experience with Spring? Do you know what '@Repository and '@Service is for?

Comment: @morsor yes, I use spring jdbc and know about ‘@Repository and ‘@Service

Comment: Then I don't quite understand what the problem is. Is it how to do inserts in three different tables using JdbcTemplate? Is it how to bundle it into a '@Service which is annotated with '@Transactional? Do you have code samples of your current '@Repository and/or '@Service?

Comment: @morsor well, in my head it's bad code :D What I mean: I make insert in REPORT table, if all good - I make loop with insert 1-20 record in CLIENT table and if all good - I make loop with insert 1-20 record in TAG table? It's very massive code. My question - may be it's can release better then I think?

Comment: Well - when you want to avoid ORM/JPA you will need to create very explicit SQL. I wouldn't call it bad code, as it is quite obvious what is going on. It is rather verbose code - but you could split it into 3 different '@Repository so the ugliness is encapsulated a bit and the '@Service looks nice

Answer (score 0):

Report Model class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "reports")
public class Report {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="report")
    private List<Client> clients;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="report")
    private List<Tag> tags;
}
```

Client Model class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "clients")
public class Client {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "report_id")
    private Report report;
}
```

Tag Model class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tags")
public class Tag {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String tagName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "report_id")
    private Report report;
}
```

Report Controller

```
Report report = new Report();
        report.setName("Report");

        List<Client> clientList = new ArrayList<>();
        Client client1 = new Client();
        client1.setName("user1");
        Client client2 = new Client();
        client2.setName("user2");
        clientList.add(client1);
        clientList.add(client2);

        List<Tag> tagList = new ArrayList<>();
        Tag tag1 = new Tag();
        tag1.setTagName("tag1");
        tagList.add(tag1);

        report.setClients(clientList);
        report.setTags(tagList);

        Report resultReport = reportRepository.save(report);
```

Use this as reference, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding ORM, a way forward would be using JDBCTemplate, which I am assuming will be injected into the 3 @Repositories below:

```
@Repository
public class TagRepository {

    public void insertreport(Report report) {
        .. do an insert using @JdbcTemplate
    }

}

@Repository
public class TagRepository {

    public void insertTags(List<Tag> tags) {
        .. do a bulk insert using @JdbcTemplate
    }   

}

@Repository
public class ClientRepository {

    public void insertClients(List<Client> clients) {
        .. do a bulk insert using @JdbcTemplate
    }

}

@Service
public class ReportService {

    @Autowire 3 @Repository above

    @Transactional
    public void addReport(Report report) {
        reportRepository.insertReport(report);
        tagRepository.insertTags(report.getTags());
        clientRepository.insertClients(report.getClients());
    }

}
```

Quite verbose code, but split into @Repositories reasonable encapsulation can make it tolerable.

Please note: JdbcTemplate is best used towards a 'stable' database where the data structure will not change.